# Is CiviCRM 4.6.x compatible with PHP 7?

Tags: php, compatiblity, php7

Is CiviCRM 4.6.x compatible with newer version of PHP, 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is planned for 4.8, but could use some help (with funding or investigating issues).

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17789

Comment: Commenting since this answer was accepted -- PHP 7 compatibility was introduced in 4.7.12 ( https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/civicrm-4712-rc-experimental-support-for-php-7-mysql-57 ). Rationally, it installs and passes the test-suite in PHP 7, so it works, but it's new and could have unforeseen issues. Risk-averse folks should stay with PHP 5 for now; early-adopters can get going with their early adoption.

Comment: And since someone will come here looking, https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19941 is the issue tracker for compatibility with PHP 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to help to identify the to-do's for CiviCRM to become php7 compatible in question: [What are the minimum and recommended changes to CiviCRM to support PHP 7?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9789/what-are-the-minimum-and-recommended-changes-to-civicrm-to-support-php-7)

Please do so, so at least an initial scope will become clear.