# What are the minimum and recommended changes to CiviCRM to support PHP 7?

Tags: php, php7

To pragmatically help CiviCRM step-by-step to support PHP7 I would like to know what the minimum and recommended changes to CiviCRM to support PHP 7?

This will help developers to identify areas of interest in order for issue https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17789 (PHP7 support) to be available.

PHP7 is significantly faster and PHP 5.6 will lose support august 2016 so it is wise to slowly work towards getting CivCRM ready for PHP7 :-)

Comment: I tried civicrm on php7 but got stuck on the installer page with fatal errors.

Comment: In the issue on JIRA, I added a [comment](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17789?focusedCommentId=86815&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-86815) on a tool (php7cc) that could help detect code that needs to be updated.

Comment: The question says PHP5.6 loses support August 2016; this is untrue. [PHP supported versions](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) currently says 5.6 is actively supported until end of 2016 and receives security fixes until end of 2018. Nevertheless, this is a substantial task which needs community engagement now to deliver on time. [If you use CiviCRM, please support this work.](https://civicrm.org/support-us)

Answer (score 4):

None any more - as of 4.7.12, CiviCRM supports PHP7

Answer (score 0):

**Check the certificates on your mail server.**

Run the following to ensure SMTP will work properly. Bad certificates will cause mail not to send and the "CRON not Running" Error.
Go to the following website:
http://www.checktls.com/

and enter you email address and press the CheckTLS button and review the output.

In my case, it highlighted that the mail server was using expired and self-signed certificates.