# Install Error DB Error: extension not found

Tags: extension, database, error, installation

Using "upload package file" or "install from folder" on a clean new Joomla 3.5.1 installation without any other extension I get this error :

**Cannot open mysql://XXX:YYY@localhost/XXX?new_link=true: DB Error: extension not found**

Tried 4.7.7 and for testing even CiviCRM 4.6.16 LTS -> same error

PHP Built On Linux dd36620 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar     17           20:50:15 UTC 2016 x86_64

Database Version mysqli 5.6.27-nmm1-log

Database Collation   latin1_swedish_ci

Database Connection Collation    utf8mb4_general_ci

PHP Version  7.0.4-nmm1

Web Server   Apache

WebServer to PHP Interface   fpm-fcgi

Joomla! Version  Joomla! 3.5.1 Stable [ Unicorn ] 05-April-2016 22:45
   GMT

Joomla! Platform Version Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable [ Curiosity ]
   24-Apr-2013 00:00 GMT

User Agent   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94
   Safari/537.36

Tried as suggested in the WIKI

php_value memory_limit 128M

php_value register_globals off

php_value max_execution_time 600

Maybe someone has an idea what I could do to get it installed, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed php-mysql?

`sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

To me, it sounds like PHP doesn't have the MySQL extension installed.

Meanwhile, at this point, CiviCRM doesn't support PHP 7, so if you do get this working, you'll run into that problem next.

Comment: the cms runs on a web space reseller, I can't apt-get packages. Is there a way for me to check for php-mysql ?
PHP 7 is not a big problem, I can .htaccess it to 5.6

Comment: It still may be that your PHP is missing the MySQL extension--it may simply be something to handle in your settings files then.

Comment: CiviCRM is not yet supported on PHP7 ([question](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8732/is-civicrm-4-6-x-compatible-with-php-7/10287#10287), [CRM-17789](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17789)). [PHP7 has removed the deprecated mysql extension](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7). Downgrade to PHP5.6 until CiviCRM is supported on PHP7.