# Unexpected T_CLONE, expecting T_STRING (PHP 7, Drupal 7, Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: drupal, php, php7

On an Ubuntu 16.04 VM with PHP 7.x, I am seeing the following error when enabling CiviCRM in Drupal 7:

> ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'clone' (T_CLONE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or '(' in require_once() (line 1 of /home/westernfriend/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(207) : eval()'d code).

Is this due to incompatibility with PHP 7, a missing dependency, or perhaps something else?

Comment: I just wanted to drop in and say thanks. Installing LTS (at the time not uo to PHP 7.0) and wondering why I was getting error after error. Fighting Index location and PHP Parse errors to no avail.... now I know why... too smart to read the docs first... duh. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP 7 is not supported yet - see [CRM-17789](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17789)

Also: [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9473/what-is-the-recommended-level-of-php-for-civicrm-there-seems-to-be-some-inconsi) and [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8732/is-civicrm-4-6-x-compatible-with-php-7)

Update (Aug 2017):  The information above was correct when it was written.  Things have moved on and PHP 7.0 is supported from 4.7.12 onwards.  Earlier versions of 4.7 don't run on PHP 7.0 and nor does any released version of 4.6.  There are discussions about adding this to 4.6 - see the same ticket.

The most current information should be on [CiviCRM PHP Requirements](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements)

Comment: According to the information in https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements PHP 7.0 is compatible. I am running 7.0.22 but still get the same error.

Comment: @Vietyank - what version of CiviCRM are you running?