# 500 Error on install

Tags: installation, php7

I'm having issues just getting CiviCRM installed.

This is a Drupal 7.55 install. I got as far as installing CiviCRM as a module but the next step is to go to the install/index.php file and that is where I get my HTTP 500 error.

Looking at the apache error log it is a PHP parse error

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'clone' (T_CLONE), expecting '('

and then a link to this file

/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(207) : eval()'d code on line 1

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: care to clarify why this is tagged webform-civicrm?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out the tags as using civicrm in the tag gave a short list that none seemed to be appropriate. Realized not using civicrm in tag gives more options. Really sorry about that. Didn't realize it

Comment: no worries, just trying to help.

Comment: best if you spell out which set of installation instructions you followed.

Comment: I followed these https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7

I've checked all the requirements

Drupal is 7.55
PHP is 7.0.18 with 512M for memory limit
MySQL is  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18 with log_bin showing off
PCRE shows enabled in phpinfo with library version 8.38 2015-11-23

I have Zend OPcache but no XCache or eAccelerator

Wasn't able to check trigger permission or threat_stack for MySQL

Comment: The line that's breaking it is pretty messed up, eval('function clone($t) { $r = $t; if (method_exists($r,"__clone")) { $r->__clone(); } return $r; }');`. Clone is a reserved work ever since I started working with PHP, so I'm guessing this code is pretty old. AFAIK CiviCRM is not fully tested with PHP7, you might save yourself a lot of effort by downgrading to 5.6

Comment: I downgraded the version of php to 5.6 and now the link works and I get to a page to start the database config. Hopefully, rest will work fine

The CiviCRM requirements should mention that it doesn't work with 7. I interpreted 5.3.3+ and anything higher than that and 7 was the default for my setup.

Anyway thank you very much

Comment: I got the same problem. Help'd be highly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't said which version of CiviCRM you are using.  CiviCRM 4.7.12 and later support PHP 7 so it should work.  This is mentioned in the requirements - https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements

Comment: See also: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8732/is-civicrm-4-6-x-compatible-with-php-7#comment17262_8733

Comment: @JohnM, you are right, thanks, I also felt in the same issue and it ran after switching php version to 5.6. 
Imagining, why it is not running in php 7.